# Format PART of a specific word in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

There's a unique, made-up word in a book I am editing. I need to italicize the first three letters of this word every time it occurs.

So far I have determined that GREP styles are my best shot at automatically formatting this word, but I have not been able to create a GREP string that works. Any help would be welcome!

**Edit:**

I managed to get a working GREP query, but this only works for me in the Find/Change dialog. I believe that these GREP strings need to be written a little differently depending on where they are used in the program...

By the way, the specific word I am looking for is `youniverse`. I need `you` to always be italicized.

My current working Find/Change GREP query is:

```
you(?=niverse)
```

This is a basic way to get the result I am looking for. Ideally this would be a GREP Style in my main paragraph style so I could procedurally apply this style every time the word occurs

Comment: **A: Find/Change:** **1)** Set the _"Find What:"_ regexp to `(\byou)(?=niverse\b)` **2)** Set the _"Change to:"_ value to `$1` **3)** Next to _"Change Format:"_ click the _"Specify attributes to change"_ icon, then select _"Basic Character Formats"_, and in the _"Font Style:"_ field select _"italic"_ from the pop up list, then click _"OK"_ button. **4)** Click the _"Change All"_ button. **B: GREP Style:** Or, if you want to add it as a _"GREP Style"_ for the Paragraph Style then set the _"To Text:"_ regexp to `(\byou)(?=niverse\b)` and set the _"Apply Style:"_ to an italic Character Style.

Comment: Thank you @RobC—I am definitely onto this thing now after getting a basic working GREP query

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match the first "Dan" of DankFarrik use this in your GREP search and apply appropriate character style:

```
(Dan|DankFarrik)
```

You can also try this one

```
((Dan)(?=kFarrik))
```